# QUERY formula to return only the latest record per email based on timestamp

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, google-sheets-query

Having this Google Sheet QUERY formula:

```
=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A4:Q, " select G,E,K,M,N,L,O,Q where not upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' and A > date '"&TEXTO(HOY()-3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E is not null and O is not null and Q contains '@' and not Q matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY(FORMULARIO!J4:Q, "select Q where upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' ", 0))&"'", 0)
```

How to return only one record per email (column Q) being the most recent one looking at date which is at column A?

TEST SHEET:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBMo42cbylrNHcf9b9QLI4oDw0H0oomCGrEAuPsBlA8/edit#gid=1465616509

Under tab "results" is the working query where i only need to filter out duplicates based on recency, leaving only the most recent one, and the unique identifier being email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

*(following OP's shared demo sheet)*

The formula to use would be:

```
=SORT(SORTN(QUERY(FORMULARIO!A4:Q, " select G,E,K,M,N,L,O,Q where not upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' and A > datetime '"&TEXTO(AHORA()-3, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' and E is not null and O is not null and Q contains '@' and not Q matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY(FORMULARIO!J4:Q, "select Q where upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' ", 0))&"'", 1),9^9,2,2,1),1,1)
```

**What was changed:**

- We wrapped your original query with the `SORTN` function to find and exclude all duplicate emails from column `Q` except the most recent one based on the Timestamp from column `A`.
- We -one more time- wrapped the results with the `SORT` function to have our final results sorted by the Timestamp.

> **Pro tip**
>   **An extra change** was also made within the main query by changing
>   `and A > date '"&TEXT(HOY()-3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`
>   **to**
>   `and A > datetime '"&TEXT(AHORA()-3, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'`
>   So we changed **`TODAY` to `NOW`**.
>
> *By doing this we **count dates making use of both the date and time present in a timestamp instead of just the date**.*

*(There is still room for minor improvements/alterations but out of the scope of this question.)*

---

**Original answer**

Taking for granted that your formula works as expected *(cannot check it without a test sheet)* but produces multiple rows you can use the [`limit`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#limit) clause in the end of your formula.

```
=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A4:Q, " select G,E,K,M,N,L,O,Q where not upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' and A > date '"&TEXTO(HOY()-3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and E is not null and O is not null and Q contains '@' and not Q matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, QUERY(FORMULARIO!J4:Q, "select Q where upper(J) = 'PAGÓ' ", 0))&"' limit 1", 0)
```

Comment: No. This Will only return one récord total i want one row per email being the most recent match

Comment: Use `ORDER BY (respective column) Desc` at end it will the most recent with `limit 1` as @marikanitsos said

Comment: Again this only returns 1 row i need múltiple rows but límite to one pero email being the most recent one when there are múltiple instances

Comment: Please share a test sheet

Comment: @marikamitsos https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBMo42cbylrNHcf9b9QLI4oDw0H0oomCGrEAuPsBlA8/edit?usp=sharing   under tab "results" is the working qury where i only need to filter out duplicates based on recency, leaving only the most recent one, and the unique identifier being email

Comment: Your sheet is private. If it is a sample copy, please make it public. If it is the original, please first make a sample copy and then make this copy public.

Comment: I'm sorry it's public now